# Text for links android

Tags: android

Hello I would like to have a link to a website but with a different text on the link like a html anchor tag `<a href="google.com">Alternative text</a>`.

Can anyone show any example on this? I have tried Linkify without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mTextField1.setText(spanned);
mTextField1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

here mTextField1 is a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) object and spanned is a [Spanned](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html) object.